# Why it fail to upload apk to google play console?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I get this error when I upload my `apk` to play console

```
Upload failed:

You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.

Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
```

I only want to remove that android permission(`READ_PHONE_STATE`) from my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change version in app build.gradle

```
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

Change it to (for example)

```
versionCode 2
versionName "1.1"
```

About permissions - you need to set privacy policy for app.

Comment: i have changed it but still problem with the android permisson (READ_PHONE_STATE)

Comment: Note the `versionName` does not need to change every update and is not related to the error; it is up to the developer: From https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning: The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

Comment: @MaD stackoverflow.com/a/39669092/9565253 Try this answer for permissions?

Comment: set the answer, if I helped you.